# Filter all html output

Tags: filters, hooks

I would like to make sure no email address is published in plain. So i developed a plugin that replace all email addresses by a spambot-safe alternative.

But some users put their email address in their blog header, outside the post loop. How can i capture and filter that?

This works:

```
        add_filter('the_content', array(&$this,"pep_replace"));
        add_filter('the_excerpt', array(&$this,"pep_replace_excerpt"));
        add_filter('the_comments', array(&$this,"pep_replace"));
```

This does not (it does not capture the email address i've added in my test theme header.php file).

```
add_filter('template',  array(&$this,"pep_replace"));
add_filter('wp_head',  array(&$this,"pep_replace"));
add_filter('shutdown',  array(&$this,"pep_replace"));
```

I'm digging into the hook documentation, but i'm out of ideas on what could be the right filter hook. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't protect against everything a user will do.  What if they hard-code an email address in the footer/header/sidebar of their theme?  The only way to capture and escape that is with output buffering ... and that can become a performance nightmare.

My recommendation would be to do two things:

1. Hook in to all of the places that make sense.
2. Provide accessible functions that allow people to escape their own content.

You've already got step 1 pretty much covered.  Email addresses most often appear in post content (`the_content` and `the_excerpt`) but might also appear in comments.  I would also recommend filtering the title and the content of sidebar widgets:

```
add_filter('the_title', array(&$this,"pep_replace"));
add_filter('widget_content', array(&$this,"pep_replace"));
```

For step 2, document a generic function that people can use to sanitize their email addresses:

```
function sanitize_email( $email ) {
    // do stuff
    return $sanitized_email;
}
```

Users can then use this rather than hardcoding their email address:

```
<p>Please contact me at <?php echo sanitize_email( 'myname@domain.com' ); ?>.</p>
```

If you weren't already filtering `the_content`, I'd recommend you create a shortcode as well ... but that's a bit redundant.

**Be very careful**

The other three hooks you've listed aren't actually filters - these are action hooks.  They're meant to be places in code where you can hook in your own logical methods.  Unlike filters, they don't `return` anything to PHP ... so they're pretty meaningless when used as filters.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough and speedy answer.  I was getting to the same conclusion: controlling the output, which is not wise given the wide WP ecosystem. I have therefore followed your advises and provided a safe_email() function. Thank you!!

Comment: If you are interested, you can find the plugin here http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pixelines-email-protector/

Answer (score 2):

**Manual method:**

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'buffer_start');    function buffer_start() { ob_start("myy_callback"); }
add_action('shutdown', 'buffer_end');       function buffer_end()   { ob_end_flush(); }


function myy_callback($buffer) {
  // modify buffer here, and then return the updated code
  $buffer = str_replace('MERCEDES','FERRARI',$buffer);
  return $buffer;
}
```