# check, if any "add_action" function contains string XXXXXXXXX

Tags: filters, actions

i want to filter out any function, that output such string  : `http://twitter.com/xxxxxx.js` (this is example,i will need other strings to filter out..)

is there any way, to find which "add_action" adds any script or link, containing that string?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve that:
I am filtering out the whole **[HTML output](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208190/33667)** before it is actually outputed.